# When it will created the objectfactory instance in jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

Iam new in Jaxb.I have one doubt on **Object factory**.The doubt is when it will be created bean instance where in objectfactory class **createXXXBean** method,When calling the UnMarshall Process.Check the below objectfactory.createFruitbean()

```
  @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://as.com/items/types", name = "fruitbean")
    public JAXBElement<Fruittype> createFruitbean(Fruittype value) {

        return new JAXBElement<Fruittype>(_Fruitbean_QNAME, Fruittype.class, null, value);
    }
```

Please help me.

**Update :-**

I didn't get any excption on above code.I have doubt on ObjectFactory.createFruitBean().In the below codesnippet, where/when it will called the method i.e., ObjectFactory.createFruitbean()

```
JAXBContext jContext=JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
UnMarshaller unmarshall=jContext.CreateMarshaller();
JAXBElement jElement=unmarshall.UnMarshall(XML_PATH);
```

Comment: What's wrong? Are you get exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

   private static final QName FRUIT_QNAME = new QName("...", "...");

   public ObjectFactory() {
   }

   public Fruittype createFruittype() {
      return new Fruittype();
   }

   @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://as.com/items/types", name = "fruitbean")
   public JAXBElement<Fruittype> createFruitbean(Fruittype value) {
      return new JAXBElement<Fruittype>(_Fruitbean_QNAME, Fruittype.class, null, value);
   }
}
```

Comment: I dont get any excpetion.Please check the above "update" comments